# Setear atributo Data desde jquery

Tags: jquery, data

```
if($(this).data('open') == 0){
        $(this).data('open',1);
    }
```

Trato de hacer algo tan sencillo como lo anterior. Este condicional está dentro de una funcion de JS. Probe poner un `alert` antes de la asignacion del dato a `data-open` y se muestra correctamente, por lo que el problema está en `$(this).data('open',1);`

> Probé reemplazar `this` por el selector del elemento, probe `('open',1)` y con `('open') = 1`. Alguien sabría decirme porque no puedo asignar el valor? Muchas gracias

> Agrego por las dudas la funcion entera

```
 $(".btn-config-mobile").on('click', function(){

    if($(this).data('open') == 0){
        $(this).data('open',1)
    }

    $('.btn-config').css({'translateY':'3rem'})
    $('.btn-config').fadeIn(200)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion `.data()` de jQuery no cambia valores en HTML.  Si eso es lo que quieres necesitas usar `.attr()` asi:

```
$(this).attr("data-open","1");
```

Cabe notar que `.attr()` solo funciona con strings, ya que trabaja directamente con HTML.

Comment: El uso del data()método para actualizar los datos no afecta los atributos del DOM. Para establecer un data-*valor de atributo, use attr.

-> Justo habia encontrado eso en la documentacion, muchisimas gracias